# jquery - after ajax value is null make div slideup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Html (if there are not results - example):

```
<div id="fixedsearch"></div>
```

Html (with results - example):

```
<div id="fixedsearch">
 <div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <img src="/imagesource.jpg">    
 </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
        data: {'states':decodeURIComponent($value)},
        success:function(data){
          $('#fixedsearch').html(data);    
          if(data == ''){
            $('#fixedsearch').slideUp();
          }else{
            $('#fixedsearch').slideDown();
          }    
        }
      });
    });
```

What I need is:

1) If data is not null (and there are existed div inside #fixedsearch) do a smooth animation like slidedown() to show the results inside the #fixedsearch,

2) If data is null do a smooth animation like slideup() to hide smoothly the div.

That is the general idea but I can't accomplished with this jquery code.

[image]

Comment: show what you have tried so far with working fiddle. it will help

Comment: What is the datatype of your response `data` in the line `$('#fixedsearch').html(data);` ?

Comment: I have a lot of code to upload and I think is impossible because app is very complex. I must convert it to a static values...

Comment: also check your style rules.... fixedSearch may have `height:auto` so it will resize as soon as you change its content. It means, the animation will run after the height is modify. If possible, update your html to allow to add a fixSearch div a fixed height... or add an enclosing div to that so you could animate opacity before clearing the content...

Comment: `If data is null` so, instead if `if (data == '')` use `if (data == null)`

Comment: Imo this much should be enough but you need to give us more info - What is the datatype & value of `data` when its empty & when its not ? Since we don't have the URL, we need to know what is the response(`data`) you are getting atleast

Comment: That I said it already. The results of html code are on the first lines. Without results and with results...

Comment: @VasilisGreece to which div should you append the response to? you are trying to append it to the div that comes in response

Comment: Yes that's right. The div I want to slide is the #fixedsearch.

Comment: @VasilisGreece but you said HTML when no reponse is `<div id="fixedsearch"></div> ` .. so I thought this itself is a resonse with empty div.. Can you tell us what the response will be?? when you say "No Response"

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is wrong. Instead of testing for `data == ''`, you should instead test for `data.length > 0` if you want to test for the presence of data to output.

```
success:function(data){
      $('#fixedsearch').html(data);    
      if(data.length > 0){
        $('#fixedsearch').slideUp();
      }else{
        $('#fixedsearch').slideDown();
      }    
    }
```

Comment: Something is missing. It didn't work as I expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some timeout delay along with `stop()` with `true` to  clear the pending animation queues that got triggered when multiple `keyup` events got triggered.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchinput').on('keyup', function() {
    //when no data from server
    data = $(this).val();
    if (data.length) {
      $('#fixedsearch').stop(true, true).slideUp(1000, function(){
         //you can do some process
      });
    } else {
      $('#fixedsearch').stop(true, true).slideDown(1000, function(){
         // you can do some process 
      });
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchinput" />
<div id="fixedsearch">
  <div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <img src="/imagesource.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When typing multiple characters the keyup is triggered multiple times. You can try adding the .stop() function or use a different event. I'm not the downvoter but maybe this is the reason he/she downvoted.

Comment: @Mike please verify. Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: When I get results the div of #fixedsearch is going to the middle of his height and then it is slidedown.

Comment: i also don't see why this was down voted. also Vasillis i don't understand what you mean with the last comment. is there more to the story than when empty slide up and when not empty slide down... if so please explain in more detail.

Comment: @TechBreak that did it!

Comment: Any upvote would be appreciated and helpful for next visitor.

Comment: @VasilisGreece did not get you. Is there anything more you are expecting to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry but you are far away from the solution. I upvote you for a courage you have.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, @VasilisGreece how is this far away from the solution. Only change I would do is cache the $('#fixedsearch') and change to applicable to what you want but that semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for length of data:

find the tag and  check if it returns length zero. If it does, there is no data returned.

```
 $('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
        data: {'states':decodeURIComponent($value)},
        success:function(data){
          var dataHtml = $('#fixedsearch',data).find('div').length;
          $('#fixedsearch').html($('#fixedsearch',data).html());    
          if(dataHtml == 0){
            $('#fixedsearch').slideUp();
          }else{
            $('#fixedsearch').slideDown();
          }    
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: After edit of your post didn't happened anything. Before you were close to the solution. Please continue.

Comment: No errors. I see after length you haven't put the ";"

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the `.html()`, check it now

Comment: can you make `console.log(data)` and show what data is returned ? BTW there was a case mismatch.. edited it now

Comment: I got the results as I expect it  (by console.log(data)) the problem is perhaps the css or the slides functions...

Comment: Maybe this code works fine, problem might be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

using **.html().length**

After appending the data into your `div` you can check the content length. You can check that by using `.html().length` on your div. Use this code in your success callback

```
   success:function(data){
      var $fixedSearch = $('#fixedsearch'); // hold the object in a variable since you are using it multiple times, Just a performance concern
      $fixedSearch.html(data);    
      if($fixedSearch.html().length == 0){  // check if the contents exist or not
        $fixedSearch.slideUp();
      }else{
        $fixedSearch.slideDown();
      }    
    }
```

Comment: for the slidedown it seems that is almost ok but for slideup the line disappeared instantly.

Comment: @VasilisGreece the default is 400 for the slide up or the slide down http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ check this documentation, you can make it evven slower by giving bigger number `.slideUp(800)`;

Comment: You are close to the solution but I know the time it doesn't seem to be the problem. When the data are null and as a result having:

<div id="fixedsearch"></div>

This div doesn't have any height to slideup... so maybe somewhere there is the solution

Comment: @VasilisGreece that is the question.. when the div doesnt have anything why to slide up? does you div have any min height? I am thinking why not we hide the div initially and only if content is there we will slide down it .. else do nothing.. will this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is problem in your code ...

I think you are missing really important property about slideDown() function as I know-

> slideDown() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and
>   display:none in CSS (but not visibility:hidden); if your div has no css like `display:none` then `slideDown()` has no effect.

and `slideUp()` will work in displayed element but you have to callback function in that. I think you should have code like below-

```
$('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
  $value=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
    data: {'states':decodeURIComponent($value)},
    success:function(data){
      // $('#fixedsearch').html(data);- this will set html to recent and if data is empty then you div  with id fixedsearch automatically hidden
      $('#fixedsearch').html(data);    
      if(data == ''){
        $('#fixedsearch').slideUp("slow",function(){
              $('#fixedsearch').html(data);
        });
      }else{
        // this will hide your div abrupty
        $('#fixedsearch').css('display':'none');
        // now set div with you new html; hope you are getting response in html 
        $('#fixedsearch').html(data);
        $('#fixedsearch').slideDown();
      }    
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I know this not perfect solution for you; but something is better than nothing... Please accept as an answer and upvote if you find helpful somewhere

Comment: you can share solution with us, please post as answer to your own question, and welcome

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I saw the height was the problem.

```
 $('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
        data: {'states':decodeURIComponent($value)},
        success:function(data){
          $('#fixedsearch').html(data); 
          $('#fixedsearch').css({"height": "296px"});
          if(data != ""){
            $('#fixedsearch').slideDown();
          }else{
            $('#fixedsearch').slideUp();
          }          
        }
      });
    });
```

Now what I need is to get the height dynamically when the div is not empty. Everything else is perfect now. Thank you for your support.